# How to create a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have this piece of code that I am trying to test:

```
def error_from_exception(ex)
  if ex.is_a?(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
...
```

To get into the if block, I need to pass in the correct `ex` param.

How do I create an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid?

With rspec, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
context 'exception is ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid' do
  it 'returns the validation error' do
    begin
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    rescue Exception => ex
      binding.pry
      ###
      # From my pry session:
      # $ ex
      # $ <ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)>
      # $ ex.class
      # $ ArgumentError < StandardError
      ###
    end


  end
end
```

How do I find out what argument type the library is looking for?

[RecordInvalid link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: This is now possible in Rails 5.1.1. The record argument is no longer required after this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4ff626cac901b41f86646dab1939d2a95b2d26bd

If you are on a Rails version under 5.1.1, see the original answer below:

It doesn't seem like it is possible to raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` by itself. If you look at the source code for `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`, it requires a record when initializing:

```
class RecordInvalid < ActiveRecordError
  attr_reader :record # :nodoc:
  def initialize(record) # :nodoc:
    @record = record
    ...
  end
end
```

(source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb)

Something you could do to work around this would be to simply create an actual record that is invalid and attempt to save it using `save!` (such as calling `User.new.save!` when `User.name` is required). However, keep in mind that this might potentially become a problem in the future if the model you use is changed and it becomes valid inside your test (`User.name` is no longer required).

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I ended up doing. It works with a valid record too, there just won't be any messages.
`let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } `
`let!(:ex) { ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(user) }`

Answer (score 7):

None of the above methods worked for me so I finally did the following while doing a spec:

```rb
class InvalidRecord
  include ActiveModel::Model
end


raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(InvalidRecord.new)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It was useful when I just do not need any specific error message but just the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` object.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do something similar to test my code's handling of `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`. I wanted to do

```
allow(mock_ar_object).to receive(:save!).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

but that gives `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` when RSpec tries to instantiate `RecordInvalid`.

Instead I wrote a `RecordInvalid` subclass and overrode `initialize` like this:

```
class MockRecordInvalid < ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  def initialize
  end
end

allow(mock_ar_object).to receive(:save!).and_raise(MockRecordInvalid)
```

Then a `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` will catch `MockRecordInvalid` and `MockRecordInvalid.new.is_a?(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)` is `true`.

Comment: It worked for me, and I just added a new `message` method so that I can do something like `error.message.include?("Kind")` inside the `rescue` section.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid needs an object to be created.
If you want to test just the exception itself, try:

```
null_object = double.as_null_object
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(null_object)
```

Understand the double as null object here (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object)

Answer (score 0):

I am using update_attribute(attr, 'value') instead of save! and I can mock the update_attribute method as follows:

```
expect(mock_object).to receive(:update_attribute).with(attr, 'value').and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can stub it to the Model like this,

`ModelName.any_instance.stubs(<method_name>).raises(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(record))`

**Example:**

`Post.any_instance.stubs(:save!).raises(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(post))`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve your code block (do formatting applied) and include an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].